# What's the best way to migrate a Django DB from SQLite to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, django, sqlite, migration

I need to migrate my db from sqlite to mysql, and the various tools/scripts out there are too many for me to easily spot the safest and most elegant solution.

This seemed to me nice http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/14/ but appears to be 3 years since getting an update which is worrying..

Can you recommend a solution that is known to be reliable with Django 1.1.1 ?

Comment: I'm guessing you already tried a `dumpdata` followed by a `loaddata`?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Execute:

```
python manage.py dumpdata > datadump.json
```

Next, change your settings.py to the mysql database.

Finally:

```
python manage.py loaddata datadump.json
```

Comment: Except sometimes this doesn't work, if you've put unicode data into strings in sql, the fixture creator and mysql don't seem to get along. At least, that's what I came here trying to figure out how to solve.

Comment: Or this doesn't work because of integrity errors...or many other issues.

Comment: Sometimes it raise "... is not JSON serializable"

Comment: Running `dumpdata > datadump.json` raises error: `CommandError: No installed app with label '>'.`

Answer (score 76):

After some hard searching I got several problems that I hope future answer looking people will find useful.

my formula is

1. `python manage.py dumpdata > datadump.json`
2. Change settings.py to your mysql
3. Make sure you can connect on your mysql (permissions,etc)
4. `python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb`
5. Exclude contentype data with this snippet in shell

   `python manage.py shell`

   `from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
   ContentType.objects.all().delete()
   quit()`
6. `python manage.py loaddata datadump.json`

Hope that will help you!

Comment: What does the contenttype data exclusion do?

Comment: @DeltaG
The canonical answer is [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/). But the best answer I found is: 

[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895429/how-exactly-do-django-content-types-work)

Comment: That worked for me too. Step 5 was needed for the loaddata command to work.

Comment: I am getting this answer django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: Problem installing fixture '/home/ubuntu/news-manifest-master/datadump.json': Comment has no content_type.

Comment: why run-syncdb? I had to run without that

Answer (score 11):

This is a neater way to avoid the `ContentType` issues described elsewhere:

```sh
./manage.py dumpdata --exclude contenttypes --exclude auth.permission --exclude sessions --indent 2 > dump.json
```

Then:

```sh
./manage.py loaddata dump.json
```

Comment: This is a useful addition; you could improve this answer by adding more steps to it like the answer by Carlos Henrique Cano.

Comment: also `--exclude admin.logentry`

Answer (score 2):

A (fuller) list of the steps I needed for moving from sqlite to MySQL, YMMV:

1. python manage.py dumpdata > datadump.json
2. Make sure you can connect on your mysql (permissions, etc)
3. Make sure you HAVE PRIVILEGES to modify FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS (I had to install and run my own private instance of mysql for that)
4. Make sure InnoDB engine is NOT used (use MyISAM in *every* table) or the next step won't work (failing silently)!
5. Relax validation by this command (this won't take effect in InnoDB):
   `SET GLOBAL FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;`
6. Load django_site.sql table separately (if using contrib.sites)
7. Change settings.py to your new mysql
8. python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
9. Fix syncdb errors errors by tinkering with the code in /migrations directories of your Django apps and the DB tables as necessary
10. Exclude contentype data with this snippet (can put it in the main urls.py module):
    `from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType`
    `ContentType.objects.all().delete()`
    `quit()`
11. If need editing json data have to prettify it first:
    `cat datadump.json | python -m json.tool > datadump_pretty.json`
12. python manage.py loaddata datadump.json
13. Fix any data truncation issues
14. Add timezone data to the database:
    `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -D mysql -P 1234 -u root -p --protocol=tcp`
    `mysql -P 1234 -u root -p -e "flush tables" --protocol=tcp`
15. Test the site is working without submitting any data
16. SET GLOBAL FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
17. Test the rest

Comment: From the official documentation: _MySQL’s default storage engine is InnoDB. This engine is fully transactional and supports foreign key references. It’s the recommended choice._