# Convert MySQL to SQlite

Tags: mysql, sqlite

Is it possible to convert from MySQL to SQLite with a free tool on windows?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18671/quick-easy-way-to-migrate-sqlite3-to-mysql

Answer (score 99):

There is a mysql2sqlite.sh script on [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/esperlu/943776#file-mysql2sqlite-sh)

As described in the header, the script can be used like this:

```
./mysql2sqlite.sh myDbase | sqlite3 database.sqlite
```

---

**alternatives**

- an updated version https://github.com/dumblob/mysql2sqlite
- A simpler script was posted at the the [MySQL Forums](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?145,68269,92627#msg-92627)

Comment: Works as charm! Here is a bit of documentation: 
`$ ./mysql2sqlite.sh -h host -u MyUserName -pMySecretPassWord myDbase | sqlite3 database.sqlite`
https://gist.github.com/943776

Comment: The script just pulls arguments from the command line and passes them to mysqldump, so you can find out about configuring custom ports, etc with `man mysql` or `man mysqldump`

Comment: It's worth noting that this script has been superseded by a successor maintained here: https://github.com/dumblob/mysql2sqlite

Comment: Even better to play with non-ascii characters: $./mysql2sqlite.sh --default-character-set=utf8 -hHost -uUser -pPass db | sqlite3 db.sqlite  https://gist.github.com/esperlu/943776#gistcomment-984448

Comment: Worked for me using `$./mysql2sqlite.sh -u MyUserName -p MyPassword --column-statistics=0 --default-character-set=utf8 MyDatabase | sqlite3 database.sqlite`

Comment: When I try to execute the script it says "Permission denied". `sudo`doesn't work either.

Comment: For anyone looking for a solution for Django, you should use its built in dumpdata 
 and loaddata command, please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034910/whats-the-best-way-to-migrate-a-django-db-from-sqlite-to-mysql

Answer (score 57):

[Here](https://www2.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ConverterTools) is a [list of converters](https://www2.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ConverterTools). ([snapshot at archive.today](http://archive.today/2020.01.29-153607/https://www2.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ConverterTools))

---

An alternative method that would work even on windows but is rarely mentioned is: use an ORM class that abstracts specific database differences away for you.  e.g. you get these in PHP ([RedBean](http://www.redbeanphp.com)), Python (Django's ORM layer, [Storm](https://storm.canonical.com/), [SqlAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org)), Ruby on Rails ([ActiveRecord](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/)), Cocoa ([CoreData](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/mac/data-management.html)) etc.

i.e. you could do this:

1. Load data from source database using the ORM class.
2. Store data in memory or serialize to disk.
3. Store data into destination database using the ORM class.

Comment: That would be extremely slow compared to piping through a script.

Answer (score 53):

Sequel (Ruby ORM) has a command line tool for dealing with databases, you must have ruby installed, then:

```
  $ gem install sequel mysql2 sqlite3 
  $ sequel mysql2://user:password@host/database -C sqlite://db.sqlite
```

Comment: Don't forget `gem install mysql` and `gem install sqlite3`

Comment: and `gem install pg` if you want to convert from or to a postgres db, sequel should have adapters for major db's

Comment: replace `mysql` with `mysql2` if you are using `mysql2`

Comment: Note: You'll need the `ruby-dev` package to build these native gem packages.

Comment: Had to use "gem install sequel mysql2 sqlite3" and then "sequel mysql2://user:password@host/database -C sqlite://db.sqlite" PERFECT

Comment: I then dug up my ruby skills and tried the answer below this one, but had to use mysql2 instead of mysql and this, "gem install sequel mysql2 sqlite3" then "sequel mysql2://user:password@host/database -C sqlite://db.sqlite" finally produced some meaningful errors. Seems I had some illegal dates in some fields, like 0004-00-00 and I had to correct those. Installed Firefox with the SQLite Manager add-on and went in and edited about 10 fields that had this problem. Reran the command and DONE! Finally.

Comment: how do I know if I should be using mysql or mysql2?

Comment: In ubuntu 14.04 works fine, using mysql2 and ruby-dev

Comment: You may need to quote the arguments if your password has shell-unsafe characters, such as a semi-colon.

Comment: mysql - `Error: Sequel::DatabaseError: SQLite3::SQLException: unrecognized token: "'"` mysql2 - `Error: Sequel::DatabaseError: SQLite3::SQLException: unrecognized token: "'����"`

Comment: Is there an attirbute to control the letter encoding?

Comment: @teawithfruit I am not sure, you can ask Jeremy Evans (https://github.com/jeremyevans), the maintainer of sequel ORM. I've heard he is very committed to the project and to help others with any issues related to it. There is an IRC channel too. http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/development.html

Comment: I've built a docker container for the sequel one liner database conversion https://blog.chib.me/how-to-convert-databases-with-one-line-of-code/

Comment: Note: You will need `libsqlite3-dev` package to install `sqlite3` gem

Comment: Note: You will need `libmysqlclient-dev` package to install `mysql2` gem (tested on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS). Possibly `ruby-dev` might be needed too (I had this installed already).

Answer (score 23):

I faced the same problem about 2 days ago when I had to convert a 20GB+ MySQL database to SQLite. It was by no means an easy task and I ended up writing [this Python package](https://pypi.org/project/mysql-to-sqlite3/) that does the job.

The upside of it being written in Python is that it's cross platform (unlike a shell/bash script) and can all be easily installed using `pip install` (even on Windows). It uses generators and chunking of the data being processed and is therefore very memory efficient.

I also put in some effort to [correctly translate most of the datatypes from MySQL to SQLite](https://github.com/techouse/mysql-to-sqlite3/blob/master/mysql_to_sqlite3/transporter.py#L136).

The tool is also [thoroughly tested](https://codecov.io/gh/techouse/mysql-to-sqlite3) and works on [Python 2.7 and 3.5+](https://travis-ci.org/techouse/mysql-to-sqlite3).

It is invokable via command line but can also be used as a standard Python class which you can include in some larger Python orchestration.

Here's how you use it:

```
Usage: mysql2sqlite [OPTIONS]

Options:
  -f, --sqlite-file PATH     SQLite3 database file  [required]
  -d, --mysql-database TEXT  MySQL database name  [required]
  -u, --mysql-user TEXT      MySQL user  [required]
  -p, --mysql-password TEXT  MySQL password
  -h, --mysql-host TEXT      MySQL host. Defaults to localhost.
  -P, --mysql-port INTEGER   MySQL port. Defaults to 3306.
  -c, --chunk INTEGER        Chunk reading/writing SQL records
  -l, --log-file PATH        Log file
  -V, --vacuum               Use the VACUUM command to rebuild the SQLite
                             database file, repacking it into a minimal amount
                             of disk space
  --use-buffered-cursors     Use MySQLCursorBuffered for reading the MySQL
                             database. This can be useful in situations where
                             multiple queries, with small result sets, need to
                             be combined or computed with each other.
  --help                     Show this message and exit.
```

Comment: Hey @techouse, this looks great! Is there any way it could work with a `.sql` dump file or does it require connection to an installed MySQL database?

Comment: Hey! Ummm, no this *requires* a working MySQL database. If you have a dump without an actual server your best bet is to change the file manually *if* you know what you're doing.

Comment: @arkadianriver I suggest you always use virtual environments with Python 

Comment: This tool was pretty awesome; great job.  I exported this to a .sql dump file by running `sqlite3 db.sql`, then executed the following commands to have sqlite generate the dump file: `.output init.sql` `.dump` `.exit` -- I will note the only unfortunate thing so far is that views weren't exported correctly, but that's not a huge deal.

Comment: Follow up to my above comment: it also appears that the defaulted values for columns are not  exported.

Comment: What encoding do you use?
Opening the file with utf-8 results in SQLite format 3   @     G  �           9      G .4    �   �����.��p&��*"                                                                                                   g=�indexfrench_index_French_typefrenchCREATE INDEX "french_index_French_type" ON "french" ("type")pC�indexfrench_index_French_articlefrenchCREATE INDEX "french_index_French_article" ON "french" ("article")�/
�9tablefrenchfrenchCREATE TABLE "french" (
 "id" INTEGER NOT NULL  ,
 //stuff
)mA�...

Comment: @SarahMultitasker SQLite uses utf8 by default. What Python are you on. Also, please take this to GitHub issues for better traction and quicker resolution

Answer (score 18):

Not every DB schema can be converted. MySQL is more complex and feature-rich than SQLite. However, if your schema is simple enough, you could dump it into an SQL file and try to import it / load it into an SQLite DB.

Comment: After dumping your MySQL database to a file, you can use this script to convert it to SQLite https://github.com/dumblob/mysql2sqlite (as mentioned in @David_LeBauer 's answer).

Answer (score 14):

Sqlite has officially list of converting tools.

http://www2.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ConverterTools

Answer (score 12):

Simplest way to Convert MySql DB to Sqlite:

1) Generate sql dump file for you MySql database.

2) Upload the file to RebaseData online converter [here](https://www.rebasedata.com/convert-mysql-to-sqlite-online)

3) A download button will appear on page to download database in Sqlite format

Answer (score 9):

I found the [perfect solution](http://web.archive.org/web/20150321051751/http://www.jbip.net/content/how-convert-mysql-sqlite)

First, you need this script (put it into a file called 'mysql-to-sqlite.sh'):

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "x$1" == "x" ]; then
  echo "Usage: $0 <dumpname>"
  exit
fi

cat $1 |
grep -v ' KEY "' |
grep -v ' UNIQUE KEY "' |
grep -v ' PRIMARY KEY ' |
sed '/^SET/d' |
sed 's/ unsigned / /g' |
sed 's/ auto_increment/ primary key autoincrement/g' |
sed 's/ smallint([0-9]*) / integer /g' |
sed 's/ tinyint([0-9]*) / integer /g' |
sed 's/ int([0-9]*) / integer /g' |
sed 's/ character set [^ ]* / /g' |
sed 's/ enum([^)]*) / varchar(255) /g' |
sed 's/ on update [^,]*//g' |
sed 's/\\r\\n/\\n/g' |
sed 's/\\"/"/g' |
perl -e 'local $/;$_=<>;s/,\n\)/\n\)/gs;print "begin;\n";print;print "commit;\n"' |
perl -pe '
if (/^(INSERT.+?)\(/) {
  $a=$1;
  s/\\'\''/'\'\''/g;
  s/\\n/\n/g;
  s/\),\(/\);\n$a\(/g;
}
' > $1.sql
cat $1.sql | sqlite3 $1.db > $1.err
ERRORS=`cat $1.err | wc -l`
if [ $ERRORS == 0 ]; then
  echo "Conversion completed without error. Output file: $1.db"
  rm $1.sql
  rm $1.err
else
  echo "There were errors during conversion.  Please review $1.err and $1.sql for details."
fi
```

Then, dump a copy of your database:

```
you@prompt:~$ mysqldump -u root -p --compatible=ansi --skip-opt generator > dumpfile
```

And now, run the conversion:

```
you@prompt:~$ mysql-to-sqlite.sh dumpfile
```

And if all goes well, you should now have a dumpfile.db which can be used via sqlite3.

```
you@prompt:~$ sqlite3 dumpfile.db 
SQLite version 3.6.10
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> .tables
dg_cities                 dg_forms                  dg_surnames             
dg_counties               dg_provinces              dg_user_accounts        
dg_countries              dg_provinces_netherlands
dg_first_names            dg_states
```

Answer (score 6):

There are different ways to do this. I also had this problem and I searched a lot and then I got a simple way to convert MySQL to SQLite.

**Follow these steps:**

1. First You Need to Install SQLite DB Browser (very small and fast to view Tables and Data)
2. Open your MySQL File in Notepad or it would be great if you open in Notepad++
3. Remove First extra Lines Contains Information or Queries and Save it.
4. Open SQLite DB Browser, Create Database, then Tables, and Same Types as it is in MySQL Database.
5. In Menu Bar of SQLite DB Browser Select File-> then Import data MySQL File which you saved.

It will easily Convert into SQLite After Warning Dialog.

If error then remove more extra lines if your MySQL file have.

You can also Install MySQL to SQLite Converter Software on trial Basis, but the information I am giving for conversion is life time.

Comment: This worked fine if your data have no character like apostrophe. For example "This is Peter's book" in sql dumb will be 'This is Peter\'s book'. This will make DB Browser throw error, for a large data it is difficult to remove. But if you import the data from phpAdmin as CSV to DB Browser, that import will be successful. I hope this help

Comment: But what "extra lines" though ? You could have incompatible data types all over the file.

Answer (score 3):

My solution to this issue running a **Mac** was to

1. Install Ruby and sequel similar to Macario's answer. I followed this link to help setup Ruby, mysql and sqlite3 [Ruby on Rails development setup for Mac OSX](http://www.createdbypete.com/articles/ruby-on-rails-development-setup-for-mac-osx/)
2. Install sequel

   ```
   $ gem install sequel
   ```

   If still required

   ```
   % gem install mysql sqlite3
   ```

   then used the following based of the Sequel doc [bin_sequel.rdoc](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/bin_sequel_rdoc.html) (see Copy Database)

   ```
   sequel -C mysql://myUserName:myPassword@host/databaseName sqlite://myConvertedDatabaseName.sqlite
   ```

A **windows** user could install Ruby and Sequel for a windows solution.

Comment: How can I copy only one table from the DB not entire mysql database ?

Comment: For a single table in the past I have done this, but there may be a better way. Export the table as csv with the column names in the first row option ticked. Then using DB Browser for SQLite, import the table into my existing sqlite database using the import table from csv option.  You will then likely have to go in and change the fields to the type you require as I believe all the fields will be set to TEXT.  In the project I was working on though we developed a process were we made an api call to return all the data in a table and then inserted/replaced the data in the apps database.

Comment: It seems to be working. Nonetheless, I cannot find where is the output file. Can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

I tried a number of methods on this thread, but nothing worked for me. So here is a new solution, which I also found to be very simple:

1. Install [RazorSQL](http://razorsql.com/features/sqlite_database_conversion.html). Works for Mac, Windows and Linux.
2. In RazorSQL connect to your database, on localhost for example. Conversion doesn't work with sql dump files.
3. Right click on your database -> Database Conversion -> select SQLite. 
   This will save a txt file with all the `sqlite` queries necessary to create this database.
4. Install a SQLite database manager, like [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/). It works on any OS.
5. Create an empty database, go to Execute SQL tab and paste the content from step 3.

That's it, now you have your SQLite database.

Comment: RazorSQL seems to just build a "common" *.sql file with table definitions and data insert intos but nothing particularly SQLite specific. It did not export Views which is a big minus. The mysqldump client which comes with MySql exports views too but it also produces lot of conditional stuff etc. what SQLite will not digest.

Answer (score 1):

If you have experience write simple scripts by Perl\Python\etc, and convert MySQL to SQLite.
Read data from Mysql and write it on SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

I like the SQLite2009 Pro Enterprise Manager suggested by Jfly. However:

- The MySQL datatype INT is not converted to SQlite datatype INTEGER (works with DBeaver )
- It does not import foreign key constaints from MySQL (I could not find any tool that supports the transfer of foreign key constraints from MySQL to SQlite.)

Answer (score 1):

From [list of converter tools](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ConverterTools) I found [Kexi](http://calligra.org/). It is a UI tool to import from various DB servers (including MySQL) into SQLite. When importing some database (say from MySQL) it stores it in Kexi format. The Kexi format is the 'native' SQLite format. So simply copy the kexi file and have your data in sqlite format

Comment: 2023 : this is the best solution, just install `sudo apt install kexi` then install the driver `sudo apt install kexi-mysql-driver` (and even postgresql), and open it, and bring it from the server, open it as a file in SQLite (and remove the extra tables created by Kexi)

Answer (score 1):

If you have been given a database file and have not installed the correct server (either SQLite or MySQL), try this tool: https://dbconvert.com/sqlite/mysql/ The trial version allows converting the first 50 records of each table, the rest of the data is watermarked. This is a Windows program, and can either dump into a running database server, or can dump output to a .sql file