# mysql to sqlite conversion

Tags: mysql, database, file, sqlite, dump

I've been trying to convert a mysql database to a sqlite db file but no luck. Is there any software that can do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert MySQL to SQlite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890518/convert-mysql-to-sqlite)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a huge list at the SQLite website.
http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ConverterTools

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890518/convert-mysql-to-sqlite for an up to date answer