# Convert instructions from MySql to Sqlite

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, insert

Is it possible to convert instructions from `MySql` to `SQlite` using some tool on MAC ? I have many instructions in `MySqlite` for inserting into tables and I need to insert in sqlite, and it would take a lot of time for changing the instructions into sqlite format for inserting.

A MySql instruction

```
INSERT INTO language_translation_fr(id_translation, content) VALUES
(2001, 'ABIDJAN LAGUNES'),
(2002, 'SUD-OUEST'),
(2003, 'NORD-OUEST'), 
(2004, 'CENTRE-EST')
```

in SQlite looks like :

```
INSERT INTO language_translation_fr
      SELECT 2001 AS 'column1', 'ABIDJAN LAGUNES' AS 'column2'
UNION SELECT 2002, 'SUD-OUEST'
UNION SELECT 2003, 'NORD-OUEST'
UNION SELECT 2004, 'CENTRE-EST'
```

Comment: I think there is no such tool :(

Comment: Where are these sql instructions? In separate files, or embedded to some other code?

Comment: in separate files, one file for each table. For a table I have about 11.000 instructions for inserting in multiples rows, like the example that I put in my question.

Comment: It looks like The MySQL insert query should be able to run in sqlite too. Why not just run it without any convert? http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890518/convert-mysql-to-sqlite
http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ConverterTools

Comment: I solved my problem. I edited all the instructions (with the help of Find&Replace)  and like this I inserted into my database. It seems that there is no such tool.