# Converting the Server MYSQL DB to SQLite DB

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite

I have a huge Database on the server and i need that DB in SQLite so that i can use it in my application in android as well as in ios app.

I got one solution for this when i go to phpmyadmin and select my db on server i exported the Tables one by one into CSV file and then imported those in my SQLite Browser one by one to get all the tables (And Then corrected column names and type manually by editing every table columns).

This way i made it as a .sqlite DB to be used in the app.

But i want to know more on these points below :

1. Is their some kind of a backend application that most developers use to convert their DB into SQLite DB. (If yes then what kind of stuff do they use)
2. Is their any PHP script that can do this stuff. (If yes then what script is used and how ?).
3. Is their any other simple way to deal with this problem of getting SQLite DB from the server. (If yes then what are the possible ways to do this ?).

Can any one get me some idea about this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890518/convert-mysql-to-sqlite

Comment: No @Jon i have iMac no windows ... And My question has some points that i want to be cleared ..

Comment: Look at the link with the top-voted answer, it gives a list of converters and there are a few Mac ones in there. ^^ (as well as shell scripts, which answers point 1.  Doing it in PHP would be inefficient at best, and they create the `.sqlite` DB for you on the server-side that you can then download however you want for the client.

Comment: what about my Points ?

Comment: I didn't flag as duplicate, was more providing the link for the tools you can use to accomplish it - but I edited the last comment to talk about your points. ^^

Comment: [Convert MySQL to SQlite](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3890518/1409082)