# MySQL structure to SQLite

Tags: mysql, sqlite, mysql-workbench

I am trying to use MySQL workbench to export my model to SQLite. I don't need the data just the structure. Do you have any suggestion? Exporting to SQL and creating tables with SQLite3 using that won't work as there are several differences between MySQL and SQLite syntaxes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert MySQL to SQlite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890518/convert-mysql-to-sqlite)

Comment: There's a difference between data and model.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know there's no tool that can convert a MySQL SQL script to SQLite. You will probably have to manually rework the generated SQL. Or you could create a MySQL schema from your model and use one of the available tools to convert that schema. Needs a detour via an existing MySQL schema, however.