# convert mysql to sqlite3

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I need suggestions on how to create a SQLite database from an old MySQL database using Windows 7. I have MySQL's .FRM and .IDB files, and a SQL File (which I believe to be a dump, not a script, unfortunately). I tried to just use sqlite's .read and got a bunch of syntax errors about lock and unlock, which is why I'm guessing it's a dump file. This is a 30 gig database, so recreating by hand isn't really an option.

Is there any way for me to do something like export to a CSV, then import it into SQLite? I tried to use [mysql2sqlite](https://gist.github.com/esperlu/943776/) with Cygwin to convert it, and got a `./mysql2sqlite.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found`.
  Any ideas?

Comment: According to [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9933603/2641825), the script [mysql2sqlite](https://gist.github.com/esperlu/943776#file-mysql2sqlite-sh) seems to be the most recent way to perform this conversion. Copy-paste the command line output that you tried in cygwin so that others can help you fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is a collection of tools in the official SQLite website.
[Wiki Link](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ConverterTools)

Comment: That list is old.. anything similar but new?