# Convert MySql script to Sqlite for Windows Phone

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, windows-phone

I've got a database exported from MySQL into a .sql script. I need to read it from a Windows Phone app written in Visual C# using SQLite 3.

Is there a way to "convert", or directly export the db from MySQL Workbench to *.sqllite?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert MySQL to SQlite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890518/convert-mysql-to-sqlite)

Comment: I need a way to read data from an SQL database converted into a script, store it and query it. Is there any fast and free way to do this?