# How to import Mysql DB into SQlite in android?

Tags: mysql, json, sqlite

I have searched many links, but cant get a clear idea about how to import or export MySQL DB into SQLite database.

1. I need to get Data's from web and displays into my android app. Before that i used web services and get data as JSON format and processed it.

   ```
   List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
   params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("xxxx", Menu_id));
   params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("yyyy", Food_id));
   JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
   JSONObject jobject = jParser.makeHttpRequest(URL, "POST", params);
   success = jobject.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
   if (success == 1) {
       JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray();
       jarray = jobject.getJSONArray("Dinner_Foods");
       for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
           final JSONObject jobj = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
           FoodItems item = new FoodItems();   
           item.setFoodIdentifier(jobj.getInt("id"));
           item.setFoodName(jobj.getString("title"));
           mFoodItems.add(item);
           }
       }
   ```
2. But now i will try to import Mysql Database file into Sqlite database, and process it.
3. For that task, i have .sql which has table name as "questions", i need to convert this table into SQlite DB and process it. Please help me to find the solution...

Answer (score 1):

You can use this tool: http://sqlite2009pro.azurewebsites.net/

With this you can import mysql data to sqlite.
For more info: here is same thead

[Convert MySQL to SQlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890518/convert-mysql-to-sqlite)

Comment: mr. ji - ruh, i had .sql file and i need to import this file into my SQLite DB on program... How to solve it... Before that i had used json formats and get's data from online... But now itself my task is get MySQL db, and import those DB fiel into SQLite and process it...

Answer (score 0):

There is a good program SQLITE manager. With this program you can work on SQLITE database. Just install it. and use. Here is the download link: http://sadig.info/SQLiteManager.rar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMvoD.jpg)