# Ruby Sqlite3 installation sqlite3_libversion_number() macOS Sierra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I'm trying to install the Metasploit framework (unimportant) and bundler is attempting to install sqlite3, which is where it fails consistently. Sqlite3 is installed (executing sqlite3 at the command line brings me into the environment) and is linked using `brew link sqlite3` (and adding the --force, for some reason) but `bundler install` fails each time with this error:

```
sudo gem install sqlite3
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
Error: Running Homebrew as root is extremely dangerous and no longer supported.
As Homebrew does not drop privileges on installation you would be giving all
build scripts full access to your system.
checking for sqlite3.h... yes
checking for pthread_create() in -lpthread... yes
checking for sqlite3_libversion_number() in -lsqlite3... no
sqlite3 is missing. Try 'brew install sqlite3',
'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
and check your shared library search path (the
location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
    --with-sqlite3-config
    --without-sqlite3-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-sqlite3-dir
    --without-sqlite3-dir
    --with-sqlite3-include
    --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
    --with-sqlite3-lib
    --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/
    --with-pthreadlib
    --without-pthreadlib
    --with-sqlite3lib
    --without-sqlite3lib


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.12 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.12/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem trying to install `gem install sequel mysql sqlite3` so I can convert from mysql to sqlite like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/11328913/539149 did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this by **specifying the built-in Mac OS X sqlite library directory** on macOS Sierra 10.12.5 (16F73):

```
$ whereis sqlite3
/usr/bin/sqlite3
# if binary is in /usr/bin then library is typically in /usr/lib
$ gem install sqlite3 -- --with-sqlite3-lib=/usr/lib
Building native extensions with: '--with-sqlite3-lib=/usr/lib'
This could take a while...
Successfully installed sqlite3-1.3.13
Parsing documentation for sqlite3-1.3.13
Done installing documentation for sqlite3 after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

I tried specifying the [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) library directory but for some reason it didn't work:

```
$ brew ls --verbose sqlite3
/usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.19.3/.brew/sqlite.rb
/usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.19.3/bin/sqlite3
/usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.19.3/include/msvc.h
/usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.19.3/include/sqlite3.h
/usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.19.3/include/sqlite3ext.h
/usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.19.3/INSTALL_RECEIPT.json
/usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.19.3/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.19.3/lib/libsqlite3.a
/usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.19.3/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.19.3/lib/pkgconfig/sqlite3.pc
/usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.19.3/README.txt
/usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.19.3/share/man/man1/sqlite3.1
$ gem install sqlite3 -- --with-sqlite3-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.19.3/lib
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
...
```

If someone knows how to specify the Homebrew library directory, please let me know because that would provide a little more control over installation (supposedly [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) works but I no longer use it).

---

For anyone curious, here's the full command to install Ruby's [Sequel](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel):

```
gem install sequel mysql sqlite3 -- --with-sqlite3-lib=/usr/lib
```

And how to convert a [Laravel Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/homestead) MySQL database listening on host port 3306 to SQLite from [my comment on the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41370565/ruby-sqlite3-installation-sqlite3-libversion-number-macos-sierra#comment76437960_41370565):

```
sequel mysql://homestead:secret@192.168.10.10:3306/my_database -C sqlite://my_database.sqlite
```

Comment: 2017-Nov-20 'gem install sqlite3 -- --with-sqlite3-lib=/usr/lib' totally solve my problem, Thanks!

Comment: If you're using bundler, this should make it work for all places you run bundler: `bundle config set --global build.sqlite3 --with-sqlite3-lib=/usr/lib`

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me on Mac High Sierra OS 10.13

```
gem install sqlite3 -- --with-sqlite3-lib=/usr/lib
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this work from Gemfile directly? Something like:

    # Add to Gemfile
    gem 'sqlite3', :lib => "/usr/lib/", :condition => :only_if_mac

Comment: This is what finally worked for me: `bundle config build.sqlite3 --with-sqlite3-include=$HOME/include --with-sqlite3-lib=$HOME/lib --with-sqlite3-dir=$HOME/bin`

Comment: To get this to work with bundler:

`bundle config build.sqlite3 --with-sqlite3-lib=/usr/lib`

Answer (score 1):

Digging into the `mkmf.log` who you will find by replacing the last part of the file pointer to the log of the installation attempt. In my case:

```
Results logged to ~/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-19/2.2.0-static/sqlite3-1.3.13/gem_make.out
```

so I find the `mkmf.log` here:

```
~/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-19/2.2.0-static/sqlite3-1.3.13/mkmf.log
```

I found a more explicit description of the errors:

```
conftest.c:13:15: error: implicit declaration of function 'pthread_create' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

conftest.c:13:15: error: implicit declaration of function 'sqlite3_libversion_number' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

So adding the `--with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"` made the trick!

```
gem install sqlite3 -- --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"
```