# Error when trying to install sqlite3 "sudo gem install sqlite3" on mac

Tags: ruby, sqlite, sqlite3-ruby

**This is the error message I am getting, how can I fix this?**

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

   current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/ext/sqlite3
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20210127-26965-q4rh0q.rb extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-sqlcipher
    --without-sqlcipher
    --with-sqlcipher
    --without-sqlcipher
    --with-sqlite3-config
    --without-sqlite3-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:467:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:546:in `block in try_link0'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tmpdir.rb:93:in `mktmpdir'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:543:in `try_link0'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:570:in `try_link'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:672:in `try_ldflags'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1832:in `pkg_config'
    from extconf.rb:35:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/sqlite3-1.4.2/mkmf.log
```

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/sqlite3-1.4.2/gem_make.out

Comment: Please add to your question the relevant last lines of `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/sqlite3-1.4.2/mkmf.log` and `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/sqlite3-1.4.2/gem_make.out`

Comment: I was actually able to fix it using this: bundle config build.sqlite3 --with-sqlite3-include=$HOME/include --with-sqlite3-lib=$HOME/lib --with-sqlite3-dir=$HOME/bin.          Got it from here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41370565/ruby-sqlite3-installation-sqlite3-libversion-number-macos-sierra

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I solved by this way :
First of all install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev like this `sudo apt install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev`
and finaly do this

```
gem install sqlite3
```

That'is it ,you got sqlite3 .