# Java MySQL to SQlite

Tags: java, mysql, sqlite, jdbc, server

I have a MySQL localhost server running on my computer that is being accessed by a java application. I need to build the application so that it will run on another users device(The database needs to be accessed). I don't own a server or static ip so I figured SQlite. The thing is I know nothing about SQLite. Does anyone know a better way to achieve the goal or if not, how to port my database and code to be compatible with SQLite.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using Java as indicated in your question, there is a java database connector library for SQLlite that you can find [here](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/sqlite-jdbc-driver/).

Using the downloads and tutorials on that linked site should help you get started with integrating SQLlite into your application. However, note that whether SQLlite is actually a good solution for your application depends on what your application is actually supposed to do. SQLlite is a smaller and simpler database platform than MySQL, so it's not meant for super-heavy usage. Having never used SQLlite myself I'm afraid I can't add much more than that, other than that if you will be installing a database such as SQLlite on the client machine, be careful not to drastically inflate the DB size.

On the topic of MySQL to SQLlite,  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890518/convert-mysql-to-sqlite) may prove helpful.

Comment: Thanks, i'll give it a go.