# C# ASP.NET MVC : is there a way to convert SQL Server database to SQLite?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sqlite

Is there a way to convert a database from SQL Server to SQLite with geometry data type?

I've tried to use [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26932/Convert-SQL-Server-DB-to-SQLite-DB):

But it has an error because of geometry data type in my database.

I want to convert the sql server using c# mvc. Because i have a web app that have an export function to a software that need a sqlite db

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert MySQL to SQlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890518/convert-mysql-to-sqlite)

Comment: sqlite should be able to handle WKT, try converting the geometry data in sqlserver to a WKT varchar column and export using that column

Comment: i cant do that. because the software that use the sqlite db needs the geometry data.