# How exactly do Django content types work?

Tags: python, django

I'm really having a difficult time grasping the concept of Django's content types. It feels very hackish and, ultimately, against how Python tends to do things.  That being said, if I'm going to use Django then I have to work within the confines of the framework.

So I'm coming here wondering if anyone can give a practical real world example of how a content type works and how you would implement it. Almost all the tutorials (mostly on blogs) I have reviewed don't do a great job really covering the concept. They seem to pick up where the Django documentation left off (what seems like nowhere).

Comment: I believe (someoone correct me if I am wrong) that Content types is something like a polymorphism, it will become a tool in your hands once your project starts having models that can have many different forms.
The tag example in the documentation is pretty straight forward, you want to be able to Tag Items, but you don't want to be specific to what kind of Items they are, after all a Tag can support, posts, pages, users, products. With the use of Content types you can create relations to various different implementation without having to know what the relating model is exactly.

Comment: Okay, so where I got tripped up is that they made a class named "TaggedItem" which wasn't clear to me. I wasn't sure then if the TaggedItem was a placeholder "bridge" class. My natural inclination would have been something like "Tag" with a property named "term".

Answer (score 409, accepted):

### So you want to use the Content Types framework on your work?

Start by asking yourself this question: "Do any of these models need to be related in the same way to other models and/or will I be reusing these relationships in unforseen ways later down the road?" The reason why we ask this question is because this is what the Content Types framework does best: it creates generic relations between models. Blah blah, let's dive into some code and see what I mean.

```
# ourapp.models
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

# Assign the User model in case it has been "swapped"
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

# Create your models here
class Post(models.Model):
  author = models.ForeignKey(User)
  title = models.CharField(max_length=75)
  slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
  body = models.TextField(blank=True)

class Picture(models.Model):
  author = models.ForeignKey(User)
  image = models.ImageField()
  caption = models.TextField(blank=True)

class Comment(models.Model):
  author = models.ForeignKey(User)
  body = models.TextField(blank=True)
  post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
  picture = models.ForeignKey(Picture)
```

Okay, so we do have a way to theoretically create this relationship. However, as a Python programmer, your superior intellect is telling you this sucks and you can do better. High five!

### Enter the Content Types framework!

Well, now we're going to take a close look at our models and rework them to be more "reusable"  and intuitive. Let's start by getting rid of the two foreign keys on our `Comment` model and replace them with a `GenericForeignKey`.

```
# ourapp.models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

...

class Comment(models.Model):
  author = models.ForeignKey(User)
  body = models.TextField(blank=True)
  content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
  object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  content_object = GenericForeignKey()
```

So, what happened? Well, we went in and added the necessary code to allow for a generic relation to other models. Notice how there is more than just a `GenericForeignKey`, but also a  `ForeignKey` to `ContentType` and a `PositiveIntegerField` for the `object_id`.  These fields are for telling Django what type of object this is related to and what the id is for that object. In reality, this makes sense because Django will need both to lookup these related objects.

### Well, that's not very Python-like... it’s kinda ugly!

You are probably looking for air-tight, spotless, intuitive code that would make [Guido van Rossum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guido_van_rossum) proud. I get you. Let's look at the `GenericRelation` field so we can put a pretty bow on this.

```
# ourapp.models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericRelation

...

class Post(models.Model):
  author = models.ForeignKey(User)
  title = models.CharField(max_length=75)
  slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
  body = models.TextField(blank=True)
  comments = GenericRelation('Comment')

class Picture(models.Model):
  author = models.ForeignKey(User)
  image = models.ImageField()
  caption = models.TextField(blank=True)
  comments = GenericRelation('Comment')
```

Bam! Just like that you can work with the Comments for these two models. In fact, let's go ahead and do that in our shell (type `python manage.py shell` from your Django project directory).

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
>>> from ourapp.models import Picture, Post

# We use get_user_model() since we are referencing directly
User = get_user_model()

# Grab our own User object
>>> me = User.objects.get(username='myusername')

# Grab the first of our own pictures so we can comment on it
>>> pic = Picture.objects.get(author=me)

# Let's start making a comment for our own picture
>>> pic.comments.create(author=me, body="Man, I'm cool!")

# Let's go ahead and retrieve the comments for this picture now
>>> pic.comments.all()
[<Comment: "Man, I'm cool!">]

# Same for Post comments
>>> post = Post.objects.get(author=me)
>>> post.comments.create(author=me, body="So easy to comment now!")
>>> post.comments.all()
[<Comment: "So easy to comment now!"]
```

It's that simple.

### What are the other practical implications of these "generic" relations?

Generic foreign keys allow for less intrusive relations between various applications. For example, let's say we pulled the Comment model out into its own app named `chatterly`. Now we want to create another application named `noise_nimbus` where people store their music to share with others.

What if we want to add comments to those songs? Well, we can just draw a generic relation:

```
# noise_nimbus.models
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericRelation
from django.db import models

from chatterly.models import Comment

# For a third time, we take the time to ensure custom Auth isn't overlooked
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

# Create your models here
class Song(models.Model):
  '''
  A song which can be commented on.
  '''
  file = models.FileField()
  author = models.ForeignKey(User)
  title = models.CharField(max_length=75)
  slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
  description = models.TextField(blank=True)
  comments = GenericRelation(Comment)
```

I hope you guys found this helpful as I would have loved to have come across something that showed me the more realistic application of `GenericForeignKey` and `GenericRelation` fields.

### Is this too good to be true?

As with anything in life, there are pros and cons. Anytime you add more code and more abstraction, the underlying processes becomes heavier and a bit slower. Adding generic relations can add a little bit of a performance dampener despite the fact it will try and smart cache its results. All in all, it comes down to whether the cleanliness and simplicity outweighs the small performance costs. For me, the answer is a million times yes.

There is more to the Content Types framework than I have displayed here. There is a whole level of granularity and more verbose usage, but for the average individual, this is how you will be using it 9 out of 10 times in my opinion.

### Generic relationizers(?) beware!

A rather large **caveat** is that when you use a `GenericRelation`, if the model which has the `GenericRelation` applied (`Picture`) is deleted, all related (`Comment`) objects will also be deleted. Or at least as of the time of this writing.

Comment: So if I use `GenericRelation` in `Post` and `Picture` then I don't need to use `object_id`, `content_type` and `content_object` in `Comment`?

Comment: It would be nice to have such clean description of the contenttype framework somewhere in the official Django documentation. As for me I did realize what this framework does only after reading this port. Thank you.

Comment: Frankly there is something close: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations but I like this one more :)

Comment: little late... but i have heard that using content type framework, your application might not scale properly. can someone please tell me if this is true or a hoax?

Comment: As with everything in programming, Karan, the answer is always "it depends."  I would say use content types.  It is a "compromise" of sorts to bypass some of the rigid fundamentals of a table oriented SQL system.  Do not prematurely optimize your app!  Django is best at getting out of your way so you can write the next generation application you have always wanted:  use it's features to your advantage!

Comment: Karan, there's some truth to it. I'm working on an application that tracks notifications for users. Each notification has a GenericForeignKey relationship to some other type of content we store. Every time a user views notifications, the ORM issues N queries to get all the related content. Hardly ideal.

Comment: Should we use it if if there is only one model that using `comments` for the benefit of intuitiveness of `something.comments` ?

Comment: What's the purpose of swapping the User model in this example? It doesn't help in understanding how generic relations work here.

Comment: Basically the query firstly finds the table and aims the object_id after the table is found. So, 1st- get table, 2nd find the object_id. Hard to get but once you understand that's it.

Comment: How can we display the `comment` field over Song model's admin?

Answer (score 1):

Ok well the direct answer to your question: ( from the django source code ) is:
[Media Types parsing according to RFC 2616, section 3.7.](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html)

Which is the tears way of saying that it reads/allows-you-to-modify/passes along the **'Content-type'** httpd header.

However, you are asking for a more practice usage example. I have 2 suggestions for you:

1: examine this code

```
def index(request):
   media_type='text/html'
   if request.META.has_key('CONTENT_TYPE'):
      media_type = request.META['CONTENT_TYPE'].split(';')[0]

   if media_type.lower() == 'application/json':
      return HttpResponse("""{ "ResponseCode": "Success"}""", content_type="application/json; charset=UTF-8")

   return HttpResponse("<h1>regular old joe</h1>");
```

2: remember django is python, and as such it wields the power of the python community.
There are 2 awesome RESTFul plugins to django. So if you want to see how deep the rabbit whole goes you can check out.

- [django rest framework](http://django-rest-framework.org/)
- [tastypie](http://tastypieapi.org/)

I suggest going through the django-rest-framework tutorial which will address 'acting on different content/types' specifically.
Note: It is common practice to use the content-type header to ['version' restful API's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389169/best-practices-for-api-versioning).

Comment: Is that to what he is referring? or to the contenttypes framework?:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/

Comment: Yeah, I was referring to the content types framework. I may not have done a good enough job conveying myself. I appreciate the response regardless. For what its worth, if that were my question, you would have knocked it out of the park =)