# Django sharing one model between two others

Tags: python, django, django-models

I built a system to review wines and foods. I quickly found myself repeating models and templates with tiny differences.

Fundamentally it seems I want a review to relate to either a food or a wine. And each food or wine can have many reviews.

I had an FK (current way) to both and just left one blank but given they're so similar I decided that wasn't wise.

I then went to abstract models to at least generify the fields (new way) but as I couldn't  link to the generic item model I had a slightly more elegant code base for the same problem.

Researching into this I'm wondering if a generic relation from the food and wine to the review is the way to go or maybe content types but I don't get quite how they work or if they are what I'm looking for.

**Current way - Wines have brands, Foods have stores and Reviews have Foods and wines**

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, null=True,blank=True)

import datetime
YEAR_CHOICES = []
for r in range(2005, (datetime.datetime.now().year+1)):
    YEAR_CHOICES.append((r,r))
YEAR_CHOICES = list(reversed(YEAR_CHOICES))

class Wine(models.Model):
    wine_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    wine_type = models.ForeignKey(WineType)
    wine_year = models.IntegerField( choices=YEAR_CHOICES, default=datetime.datetime.now().year)

    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand)

class Store(models.Model):
    store_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.store_name

class Food(models.Model):
    food_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    food_desc = models.CharField(blank=True,max_length=100)

    store = models.ForeignKey(Store)

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.store.store_name +' - '+self.food_name

class Review(models.Model):
    rating = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    comment = models.CharField(blank=True,max_length=100)
    food = models.ForeignKey(Food, blank=True,default=None,null=True)
    wine = models.ForeignKey(Wine, blank=True,default=None,null=True)

    class Meta():
        ordering = ['-date']
```

**New Way - Wines and Foods are Items, Stores and Brands are Sources, but reviews still need both Wines and foods**

```
class Source(models.Model):
    name =  models.CharField(max_length=30)
    desc = models.CharField(blank=True,max_length=100)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Item(models.Model):
    name =  models.CharField(max_length=30)
    desc = models.CharField(blank=True,max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True



class WineSource(Source):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, null=True,blank=True)
    class Meta():
        ordering = ['location', 'name']

class FoodSource(Source):
    def __str__(self): 
        return self.name

import datetime
YEAR_CHOICES = []
for r in range(2005, (datetime.datetime.now().year+1)):
    YEAR_CHOICES.append((r,r))
YEAR_CHOICES = list(reversed(YEAR_CHOICES))

class Wine(Item):

    wine_type = models.ForeignKey(WineType)
    wine_year = models.IntegerField( choices=YEAR_CHOICES, default=datetime.datetime.now().year)

    source = models.ForeignKey(WineSource)

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.source.name +' '+self.name+ ' ' + str(self.wine_type)+ ' '+ str(self.wine_year)

class Food(Item):


    source = models.ForeignKey(FoodSource)

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.source.name +' - '+self.name

class Review(models.Model):
    rating = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)

    food = models.ForeignKey(Food, blank=True,default=None,null=True)
    wine = models.ForeignKey(Wine, blank=True,default=None,null=True)
    #Doesn't work as it's abstract- item = models.ForeignKey(Item,null=True)

    class Meta():
        ordering = ['-date']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [Generic Foreign Key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) is the answer. Something like:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class Product(models.Model):
     ...

class Food(Product):
     ...

class Wine(Product):
     ...

class Review(models.Model):
    ...

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

This allows us to relate a review to any single record of any model in our project. The `content_type` field tracks which model you are trying to relate to (`Food` or `Wine` in this case). The `object_id` field track which record in the `Wine` or `Food` table we are trying to track. `content_object` is a convenience attribute that allows us direct access to the object (once the review has been saved).

When creating a new review you just assign the `Wine` or `Food` to the `content_object` field:

```
wine = Wine.objects.get(...)
review = Review(..., content_object=wine)
review.save()
```

Comment: After looking around can I not do the following (taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895429/how-exactly-do-django-content-types-work):

reviews= generic.GenericRelation('Review')



As for usability. I also look up reviews for a given wine (using some kind of helper that I don't quite understand)... Wil that work?

i.e. in a template {% for review in wine.review_set.all %}

Comment: {% for review in wine.reviews.all %} and every variation I can think of no longer work :/

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [Multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) instead of an `AbstractClass` for `Item`. Then you can set a direct `ForeignKey` to `Item` in `Review`.
You can also combine this with [`InheritanceManager`](http://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managers.html#inheritancemanager):

```
from model_utils.managers import InheritanceManager

class Item(models.Model):
    name =  models.CharField(max_length=30)
    desc = models.CharField(blank=True,max_length=100)    

    objects = InheritanceManager()    

class Wine(Item):

    wine_type = models.ForeignKey(WineType)
    wine_year = models.IntegerField( choices=YEAR_CHOICES, default=datetime.datetime.now().year)

    source = models.ForeignKey(WineSource)

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.source.name +' '+self.name+ ' ' + str(self.wine_type)+ ' '+ str(self.wine_year)


class Food(Item):

    source = models.ForeignKey(FoodSource)

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.source.name +' - '+self.name

class Review(models.Model):
    rating = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)

    item = models.ForeignKey(Item,null=True)

    class Meta():
        ordering = ['-date']
```

Then you can filter like this:

```
wine_reviews = Review.objects.exclude(item__wine__isnull=True)

food_reviews = Review.objects.exclude(item__food__isnull=True)

# and all item (directly sub-classed as wine or food:
items = Item.objects.select_subclasses().all()
```

Comment: I think this is a really cool technique and I could see it working where I wanted something more 'OO' but simple inheritence through an abstract class is enough for my code re-use