# Django generic model ListViews & forms

Tags: python, django, django-views

Following from my question [Django sharing one model between two others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35758692/django-sharing-one-model-between-two-others/35759484#35759484) which explored the best way to generically manage two similar models and their dependencies. I've now come to the next part - the views.

After a bit of tweaking around I've come to the following generic listview to represent the objects.

Is this coherent? Should the urls manage the models like this?

I believe if I refine their logic I can just subclass this itemlist and add additional logic in the future so it should be future-proofed.

A class that

```
urls.py excerpt

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^item/(?P<model>\w+)/$',views.ItemList.as_view(),name='generic'),
    url(r'^item/(?P<model>\w+)/(?P<pk>\d+)$',views.ItemList.as_view(),name='generic'),
]
```

views.py excerpt

```
class ItemList(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'itemlist'
    template_name = 'food/item.html'
    model = None

    def get_queryset(self):
        model = apps.get_model('food',self.kwargs.get('model'))
        if self.kwargs.get('pk'):
            print ('pk provided')
            return model.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        else:
            print ('all')
            return model.objects.all()
```

food/item.html excerpt (using registered filter to get class name for object)

```
{% block content %}
{% for item in itemlist %}
...
{% for review in item.reviews.all %}
{% endfor %}
...
<a href="/{{ item|to_class_name}}/{{ item.id }}/addreview" class="btn btn-default btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"> Add Review </span></a>
{% endblock %}
```

Also - can I carry this attitude into my forms (again assuming that when I add a review it'll generically link back to whatever object it came from?) or is that where I should start breaking them up?