# Django model foreign key not installed or abstract

Tags: django, django-models

im creating 2 models in django, the first one has django auth user as a foreign key, the second has this first model as a foreign key like this in models.py :

```
class SGIUsers(models.Model):
    charge = models.CharField('Cargo', max_length=80)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)



class ResponsibleStateFlow(ModelBase):
    user = models.ForeignKey(SGIUsers, verbose_name = 'Responsable', blank = False )
    process= models.ForeignKey(Process, verbose_name='Proceso')
```

But i get this error :

```
sgiprocess.ResponsibleStateFlow.user: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'SGIUsers', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
```

I already imported django auth user of course. Any idea ??

Comment: Have you checked your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting?

Comment: Yes of course, everything in order there.

Answer (score 1):

try to add the app name:

```
field=models.ForeignKey('app_name.ModelName')
```

Comment: Not working =(, says app is not defined but it actually is, if i delete ResponsibleStateFlow model all works fine.

Comment: what is the ModelBase class doing

Comment: It just adds fields like created_date, deleted...nothing else. I tried using models.Model instead of ModelBase too but same result

Comment: Can you please post the code of your User class also SGIUsers.

Comment: the User class im using it's the django default model, the one included in admin, im just calling it as a foreign key

Comment: try this, it is more easier https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/contenttypes/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895429/how-exactly-do-django-content-types-work

Answer (score 1):

Found it, i needed to define an app label with the app name in class meta for SGIUsers like this first:

```
class Meta:
        app_label = 'app_name'
```

And then call the foreign with 'app_name.Modelname'