# Django :How can I let my modelChoiceField take two possible types of models

Tags: django, forms, django-models, modelchoicefield

I need to let a modelChoiceField have the possiblity of taking two different models objects.
for example can `billnum` take as queryset: `facture_ventes.objects` or `facture_depc.objects`  at the same time instead of only one model :

```
billnum=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=facture_ventes.objects)
```

Thank You For your Help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895429/how-exactly-do-django-content-types-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that the models have the same fields.  You may want to redesign your project so that you have one model and maybe an extra field on that model that differentiates between `ventes` and `depc`.  This is my recommendation.

Otherwise, you might be able to use a [union](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#union) query.

```
billnum = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset=facture_ventes.objects.union(facture_depc.objects.all())
)
```

Even then, somehow you would have to be able to distinguish between the pks of `facture_ventes` and `facture_depc`.  It's too complicated.  Change your model.