# django switch from sqlite to mssql

Tags: python, sql-server, django

Iam a newbee to Django.. i created a project using the default sqlite database backend.. but now i want to switch the database to mssql.. what all steps to follow? what all installations needed.. how to configure the database ??what all changes to the code are needed??
please someone explain in details in laymen terms..

i googled it and got the information in pieces.. One method I found was here
[What's the best way to migrate a Django DB from SQLite to MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034910/whats-the-best-way-to-migrate-a-django-db-from-sqlite-to-mysql)
of dumping to json then reloading..

but what all steps to follow before that.. please explain in detail!!

Comment: I know it's not your question, but would you be open to using PostgreSQL instead? It is generally considered to have a higher DB integrity, among other benefits. Also, it is (I believe) the DB of choice for Django.

Comment: No. I would've gone for PostgreSQL.. But I want to configure mssql only.. As it is demanded by the people for whom im making the app. @hybrid

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use some backend that supports MsSQL for Django, as it is not supported by default. One example is https://django-mssql.readthedocs.org/ . If you can get that configured then I believe you should be able to import the json export.