# Django Switching sqlite3 to Postgres - User Unique Constraint Error

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql, django-models

Was following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50323012/23097706) to switch my project database from sqlite3 to PostgreSQL, and encountered error when executing `python manage.py loaddata datadump.json`, [my json file(google drive)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kk7aCm9tuh7s6K09ThLyZiQisFVDXohj/view?usp=sharing):

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: Problem installing fixture 'C:\stuff\code\django-test01\django_project\datadump.json': Could not load auth.User(pk=1): duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_profile_user_id_key"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(1) already exists.
```

I aslso tried doing `python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb`, `python manage.py dumpdata --exclude auth.permission --exclude contenttypes --natural-foreign --natural-primary > db.json` and 'TRUNCATE django_content_type CASCADE;' in dbshell, but none of above did work.

Am using Django's built-in User model('User' class from 'django.contrib.auth.models').

Tried to completely erase data from database and do it again, but for no avail. Tried answers([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3077079/23097706), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36394793/23097706)) from related questions, but they didn't work.

What can I do to fix it and migrate my data from sqlite3 to Postgres?