# Django MySQL Table already exists

Tags: python, mysql, django, ubuntu-18.04

I have django running on ubuntu, and I am trying to set it up with mysql as db. I followed these ([1](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-18-04), [2](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-mysql-or-mariadb-with-your-django-application-on-ubuntu-14-04), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034910/whats-the-best-way-to-migrate-a-django-db-from-sqlite-to-mysql)) guides, but when I run `python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb` I get the error `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1050, "Table 'myapp_mymodel' already exists")`. How do I fix this (I am using MySQL version 5.7.41, Ubuntu 18.04, Python 3.6, Django 3.2)?

migrations:

```
admin
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
 [X] 0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices
auth
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
 [X] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
 [X] 0008_alter_user_username_max_length
 [X] 0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length
 [X] 0010_alter_group_name_max_length
 [X] 0011_update_proxy_permissions
 [X] 0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
myapp
 [ ] 0001_initial
 [ ] 0002_alter_user_uid
sessions
 [ ] 0001_initial
```

Comment: Did you populate your DB from a backup/script or have you just run migrations?  Can you add the output you get from running `python manage.py showmigrations` to your question?

Comment: @IainShelvington I just ran migrations, no backup/script. Also, I have now added the output from showmigrations.

Comment: Unfortunately MySQL does not support transactions for schema changes so when a migration fails (as seems to be the case here) you'll need to undo the changes manually. Luckily it's the initial migration so you can just delete all tables for that app - delete all the tables with the prefix `myapp_` in the DB

Comment: so do I delete, migrate, then add and repeat?

Comment: Delete all the tables prefixed with `myapp_` then run migrate again, you shouldn't get the table already exists error

Comment: @IainShelvington I did that, but now I am getting the error ```django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1170, "BLOB/TEXT column 'uuid' used in key specification without a key length")```. uuid is ```models.TextField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)```, and it used to be unique=True, but I set unique to False now.