# Django MySQL UUID

Tags: mysql, django, uuid

I had a django model field which was working in the default sqlite db:

`uuid = models.TextField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)`.

However, when I tried to migrate to MySQL, I got the error:

`django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1170, "BLOB/TEXT column 'uuid' used in key specification without a key length")`

The first thing I tried was removing the `unique=True`, but I got the same error. Next, since I had another field (which successfully migrated ):

`id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)`

I tried changing uuid to UUIDField, but I still get the same error. Finally, I changed uuid to:

`uuid = models.TextField(editable=False)`

But I am still getting the same error when migrating (DROP all the tables, makemigrations, migrate --run-syncdb). Ideally, I want to have a UUIDField or TextField with default = uuid.uuid4, editable = False, and unique = True, but I am fine doing these tasks in the view when creating the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `max_length` for your uuid field. Since UUID v4 uses 36 charactes, you can set it to `max_length=36` (make sure you don't have longer values in the db already):

```
uuid = models.TextField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True, max_length=36)
```

Comment: I just tried this, getting the same error.

Comment: How do you "migrate" to the new db?

Comment: I do python manage.py dbshell, then I do DROP TABLE for each of the tables in my app, then I exit and do python manage.py makemigrations, and python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb.

Comment: Why do you drop tables when you migrate to a new database? It should be empty? And do you remove the old migration files? Since you use migrations, you don't need `--run-syncdb` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29683494/what-should-i-use-instead-of-syncdb-in-django-1-9). I recommend using an `UUIDField` in the new database anyway.

Comment: I drop the tables because if not I get a different error (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75494608/django-mysql-table-already-exists) . I tried with UUIDField as well, but same error, but that seems weird, because I don't think UUIDField is considered BLOB/TEXT type.

Comment: I think you have trouble with your migrations. If I get you right just do the following: 1. make sure you have a fresh database without any tables 2. remove ALL your migrations files 3. generate migrations file with `makemigrations` 4. migrate to your new db with `migrate`